# Azure Build Pipeline Error in using ReSharper code quality check task in YAML pipeline

Tags: azure, devops

I am trying to make an Azure DevOps build pipeline (YAML one) for a .net core web app that runs nuget tool installer, builds the app and then runs **Resharper code analysis** on the solution.

I have given the solution path in ReSharper is:

```
- task: ResharperCli@2
  inputs:
    solutionOrProjectPath: Main/BIE.EcoPro/BIE.EcoPro.sln
    failBuildLevelSelector: 'Warning'
```

When I manually run this pipeline I get the following warnings and the ReSharper task take more than one hour to run:

[image: Warning message on ReSharper]

Can you please help me to resolve this warning message and also suggest me how to reduce the job run time for ReSharper?